# Visa required for transfer through Amsterdam airport

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen-visas, airport-transfer, uk-citizens

I'm a UK citizen travelling from Aberdeen UK to Thailand through Amsterdam. Do I need a visa for a 2-hour layover in the Amsterdam airport? Both flights are KLM and are in/out of AMS.

Do I need a Schengen visa?

Comment: Depending on your citizenship you may need a Type A (Airport Transit) Schengen Visa.

Comment: See https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy/who-must-apply-schengen-visa_en and https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/netherlands/entry-requirements

Answer (score 3):

No, UK citizens do not require a Schengen Visa to enter the Schengen Area (including Airport transit).

Comment: Given these are both non-Schengen flights,OP will likely stay in the non-Schengen airside of Schiphol and never pass immigration at all (unless they have to re-check luggage due to having two separate tickets).

Comment: With both flights on KLM it is even possible that the luggage gets checked through even when traveling on two tickets.